R Open modal on menuItem click, but only once
I would like to open a modalDialog window by clicking on a menuItem tab. The similar question was asked and answered here, which I use as a template:
Open modal on menuItem click
The difference to my question is that I want to show this modalDialog only once. If you click on the menuItem tab the second time, this modalDialog should not be displayed.
If the widgets tab were in the first place, you could use observeEvent(once = TRUE). Because the widgets tab comes only in third place a new solution is needed.
Can someone help my with my problem?
Here ist my reproducible example:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

## UI ##

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
                menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard"),
                menuItem("Subitems", tabName = "subitems",
                         menuSubItem("Upload", "upload"),
                         menuSubItem("Browse", "browse")
                ),
                menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput('tab')
  )
)

## server ##

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$tab <- renderUI({
    paste("The selected tab is", input$sidebarmenu)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$sidebarmenu, {
    req(input$sidebarmenu == "widgets")
    showModal(
      modalDialog(title = "You selected Widgets", "Or did you?")
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Many thanks in advance!

Just set a flag in the body of your server function.  Check its value in the observer, and change its value when displaying the modal for the first/only time.

This seems to do the trick:
server <- function(input, output) {
  needToShowModal <- TRUE
  
  output$tab <- renderUI({
    paste("The selected tab is", input$sidebarmenu)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$sidebarmenu, {
    req(input$sidebarmenu == "widgets")
    if (needToShowModal) {
      showModal(
        modalDialog(title = "You selected Widgets", "Or did you?")
      )
      needToShowModal <<- FALSE
    }
  })
}


Next time, please add the necessary library calls to your MRE.

You need to change needToShowModal <- FALSE to needToShowModal <<- FALSE.
Now your answer is working. Thanks ;)

So there is no need for anything fancy as observeEvent already has a once = TRUE option, for the eventExpr just add this: req(input$sidebarmenu == "widgets"). Note that this will be activated once per session
observeEvent(req(input$sidebarmenu == "widgets"), {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(title = "You selected Widgets", "Or did you?")
    )
  },once = TRUE)


Yes your suggested solution would work if you click on the widgets-menuItem as a second action.
However, if you have clicked on several menuItems before and then click on the widgets-menuItem, this solution does not work.

@TobKel, you're right, see my updated answer that uses req in the observeEvent, which does what you want
